# Google Map API: How is a geocode request defined?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to figure out the usage limitations of Google Map API. As I understand the usage limitations are like the following:

MAP LOADS:
25,000 per day

GEO CODES:
Users of the free API:
2,500 requests per 24 hour period.
5 requests per second.

Google Maps API for Work customers:
100,000 requests per 24 hour period.
10 requests per second.

Based on this I have a few questions:
1. What defines a geocode request? If for example I would like to place a pin on a map based on an address how is the number of geocode requests calculated?

2. The same goes for map loads, what defines a single map load?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. One geocoded address = one geocode request (I think this is quite clear)
2. https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload

> A single map load occurs when:
>
> a) a map is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API v3 when loaded by a web page or application;
>
> b) a Street View panorama is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API v3 by a web page or application that has not also displayed a map
>
> c) a single request is made for a map image from the Static Maps API; or
>
> d) a single request is made for a panorama image from the Street View Image API.
>
> The degree to which a user interacts with a map once it has been loaded has no impact on the usage limits. Note that the display of a Street View panorama using the JavaScript Maps API v3 by an application that has already displayed a Map using the Maps API on the same page does not incur an additional map load.